# GitHub authorize button doesn't work inside WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I wanna provide a custom browser inside app to the user could pass authorization on **GitHub.com**. But **Authorize** button is disabled in `WebView`.
[image: Screenshot]

I set recommended flags from other questions on **stackoverflow** but it didn't help. There is my `ViewModel` below where you can see flags and clients that I set for `WebView`:

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var url: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField()

    var isLoading: ObservableBoolean = ObservableBoolean()

    val webViewClient: WebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }

        override fun onReceivedError(
            view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest,
            error: WebResourceError
        ) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            isLoading.set(false)
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            isLoading.set(false)
        }
    }

    val webChromeClient: WebChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

    val webViewConfig: IWebViewConfig = object : IWebViewConfig {

        override fun onConfig(webView: WebView) {
            webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
            webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
            webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
            webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
            webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
            webView.settings.userAgentString = "Android"
        }

    }

    fun onRefresh() {
        isLoading.set(true)
        url.notifyChange()
    }
}
```

**Where can the problem be?**

Comment: Does the authorization works in a normal browser on a pc by example?

Comment: @Steven yes, and in mobile Chrome too. It doesn't work on some Android 5.x phones only

Comment: If it's only not working on Android 5.x than maybe decide to drop support? https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards the market share isn't that big.

Comment: @Steven, seems I will need to drop really, I can't get reasons of that issue.

Comment: I wish I could help you but out of my experience sometimes you can't explain it and you just need to drop support for it.